# Работа с Excel в Delphi (очистка памяти)

Tags: delphi

Работаю с Excel в Delphi 7 через OLE. Как создать файл, что-то в нём поменять и закрыть, проблем не возникает. Но мне нужно так же открывать сохранённый в БД (MSSQL) файл Excel для просмотра. Работаю с Excel так:

```
ExlApp := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
try
  ExlApp.Workbooks.Open(XLSFile);
  Sheet := ExlApp.Workbooks[ExtractFileName(XLSFile)].WorkSheets[1];
  ...
finally
  ExlApp.DisplayAlerts := false;
  ExlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close(SaveChanges:=False);
  ExlApp.Application.Quit;
  Sheet := Unassigned;
  ExlApp := Unassigned;
end;
```

Если же мы будем только открывать файл Excel, то есть кусок кода:

```
  ExlApp.DisplayAlerts := false;
  ExlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close(SaveChanges:=False);
  ExlApp.Application.Quit;
  Sheet := Unassigned;
  ExlApp := Unassigned;
```

будет отсутствовать, то нужно ли потом очищать память (когда пользователь закроет документ Excel), выделенную под ExlApp и если да,то каким образом?

Comment: Обязательно нужно закрывать иначе Excel будет висеть в процессах, т.е. сколько раз создадите ExlApp, столько и будет висеть.Добавьте еще ExlApp.Application.Quit; за блоком try-finaly

Comment: кстати, как раз для формата OLE Compound Document (то есть например XLS, но не XML и не XLSX) можно было открывать документ напрямую из памяти, не сохраняя на диск в промежутке.

Answer (score 3):

На самом деле нужно было написать так:

```
try
...
finally 
  ExlApp.Visible:=True; 
  Sheet := Unassigned; 
  ExlApp := Unassigned; 
end;
```

Мы освобождаем память и программа работает дальше. А документ Excel пользователь сам закроет, когда посчитает нужным.